# Test http-on-modify-request observer via sdk/system/events?

Tags: javascript, events, firefox-addon-sdk

Is it possible to test a [`http-on-modify-request`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Observer_Notifications#HTTP_requests)-Observer?

The [`events` module](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Low-Level_APIs/system_events) offers an `emit(type, event)` method to create Firefox events. To test a module listening to a `http-on-modify-request`, you can set the type to `http-on-modify-request`. The question is **how to set the `event` parameters to mimic a web request**? The documentation states

> **event : object**
>  An optional object with data and subject attributes. data refers to a string that you would like to pass
>   through this event. subject should refer to the actual actor/subject
>   of this event (ie: the object emitting the event).

Setting `event.data` gets passed on as the `data` parameter of the observer, same for f.ex. a string as an `event.subject`, but when I tried to pass an object with a `QueryInterface`-function, it did not work:

```
events.emit("http-on-modify-request", {"subject": {
    QueryInterface : function() {
        return {"URI": {"spec": 'mock://URI.spec'}}
    }}});
```

Code to be tested is very similar to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Low-Level_APIs/system_events.

---

@humanoid's answer to use

```
obs.notifyObservers(
    { QueryInterface : function() {
        return {"URI": NetUtil.newURI("mock://URI.spec") };
    }},
    "http-on-modify-request",
    null);
```

failed with

> JavaScript Error: "NS_NOINTERFACE: Component returned failure code:
>   0x80004002 (NS_NOINTERFACE) [nsISupports.QueryInterface]" {file:
>   "resource://gre/modules/commonjs/toolkit/loader.js ->
>   resource://addon-id/caller.js" line: xy}]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `emit` method from `sdk/system/events` is not useful to create observer notifications that look like notifications from Firefox, because it adds wrappers to ensure weak references.

Instead I would suggest to use the ["vanilla" observer service](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Reference/Interface/nsIObserverService), for example from `Services.jsm`:

```
const { Services: { obs } } = require("resource://gre/modules/Services.jsm");
```

Comment: Thank you very much for preventing me from going down that route. Do you happen to have some example code lying around, or not?

Comment: @user Using nsIObserverService for this specific case? Not really. But the notifyObservers method should be pretty straight forward to use.

Comment: Just using this, I got a `JavaScript Error: "NS_NOINTERFACE: Component returned failure code: 0x80004002 (NS_NOINTERFACE) [nsISupports.QueryInterface]" {file: "resource://gre/modules/commonjs/toolkit/loader.js -> resource://addon-id/caller.js" line: xy}]`

Comment: @user problem here, is that you're not properly creating an nsIURI with your object. It's probably better to use `const { NetUtil } = require("resource://gre/modules/NetUtil.jsm"); const url = NetUtil.newURI("mock://URI.spec");` to create the nsIURI. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/JavaScript_code_modules/NetUtil.jsm#newURI%28%29 for the method's documentation.

Comment: using `NetUtil` produced the same error (see above)

Comment: Accepted. Seems like the is the answer, and the only thing lacking is my expertise.